# php calendar not showing events farther than a month out

Tags: php, mysql, date, events, calendar

im trying to set up this php event calendar i found online. however i can only get it to display events for the month of february and march. no other events from the mysql database will show. i believe the error is in this section of code. ive been messing with this for 2 days and hate asking for help cause i really just wanna figure it out. but can anyone help please?

```
/* get all events for the given month */
$events = array();

$month = str_pad($month,2,0 , STR_PAD_LEFT);
$query = "SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS event_date FROM events WHERE event_date LIKE '$year-$month%'";
$result = $db_link->query($query) or die('cannot get results!');
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $events[$row['event_date']][] = $row;
}
```

heres the whole thing if thats not enough or anyone just wants to see it:

```
<?php
/* draws a calendar */
function draw_calendar($month,$year,$events = array()){

    /* draw table */
    $calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

    /* table headings */
    $headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';

    /* days and weeks vars now ... */
    $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_this_week = 1;
    $day_counter = 0;
    $dates_array = array();

    /* row for week one */
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

    /* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
    for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>';
        $days_in_this_week++;
    endfor;

    /* keep going with days.... */
    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;">';
            /* add in the day number */
            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';

            $event_day = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$list_day;
            if(isset($events[$event_day])) {
                foreach($events[$event_day] as $event) {
                    $calendar.= '<div class="event">'.$event['title'].'</div>';
                }
            }
            else {
                $calendar.= str_repeat('<p>&nbsp;</p>',2);
            }
        $calendar.= '</div></td>';
        if($running_day == 6):
            $calendar.= '</tr>';
            if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
            endif;
            $running_day = -1;
            $days_in_this_week = 0;
        endif;
        $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
    endfor;

    /* finish the rest of the days in the week */
    if($days_in_this_week < 8):
        for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>';
        endfor;
    endif;

    /* final row */
    $calendar.= '</tr>';


    /* end the table */
    $calendar.= '</table>';

    /** DEBUG **/
    $calendar = str_replace('</td>','</td>'."\n",$calendar);
    $calendar = str_replace('</tr>','</tr>'."\n",$calendar);

    /* all done, return result */
    return $calendar;
}

function random_number() {
    srand(time());
    return (rand() % 7);
}

/* date settings */
$month = (int) (isset($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
$year = (int)  (isset($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));
/* select month control */
$select_month_control = '<select name="month" id="month">';
for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
    $select_month_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $month ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,$year)).'</option>';
}
$select_month_control.= '</select>';

/* select year control */
$year_range = 7;
$select_year_control = '<select name="year" id="year">';
for($x = ($year-floor($year_range/2)); $x <= ($year+floor($year_range/2)); $x++) {
    $select_year_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $year ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.$x.'</option>';
}
$select_year_control.= '</select>';

/* "next month" control */
$next_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 12 ? $month + 1 : 1).'&year='.($month != 12 ? $year : $year + 1).'" class="control">Next Month &gt;&gt;</a>';

/* "previous month" control */
$previous_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 1 ? $month - 1 : 12).'&year='.($month != 1 ? $year : $year - 1).'" class="control">&lt;&lt;    Previous Month</a>';


/* bringing the controls together */
$controls = '<form method="get">'.$select_month_control.$select_year_control.'&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$previous_month_link.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$next_month_link.' </form>';

/* get all events for the given month */
$events = array();
$month = str_pad($month,2,0 , STR_PAD_LEFT);
$query = "SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS event_date FROM events WHERE event_date LIKE '$year-$month%'";
$result = mysql_query($query,$db_link) or die('cannot get results!');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $events[$row['event_date']][] = $row;
}

/* get all events for the given month */

echo '<h2 style="float:left; background-color: #9C9; padding-right:30px;">'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)).' '.$year.'</h2>';
echo '<div style="float:left;">'.$controls.'</div>';
echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
echo draw_calendar($month,$year,$events);
echo '<br /><br />';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You basic query is:

```
SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS event_date
FROM events
WHERE event_date LIKE '$year-$month%';
```

Don't use `like` on directly on dates.  There is an implicit conversion to a string, and it might not be in the format you expect.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS event_date
FROM events
WHERE date_format(event_date, '%Y-%m') LIKE '$year-$month%';
```

You could also do:

```
SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS event_date
FROM events
WHERE year(event_date) = $year and month(event_date) = $month;
```

Comment: hmm this still only shows february and march events. also in my mysql db "event_date" is of the date type if that makes a difference anywhere.

Comment: @Nick . . . What are the arguments you are using?  Your query as written returns data for one month.

Comment: i mean when i use the next and previous month buttons it shows an empty calendar for all months except february and march. i added an event for feb 2013 and that shows up on the calendar fine. but january 2014 wont show. nor will any of the 15 other random dates i added. the 5 events in the database in feb and march months show fine though. thanks for your help!

Comment: @Nick . . . The SQL code is probably fine.  The problem is in how you are setting `$month` and `$year` when these buttons are pressed.

Comment: even if i type in the url manually it acts the same though. ex: localhost/...show_calendar.php?month=4&year=2014&submit=Go returns a blank calendar when there should be an event april 1 2014

Comment: @Nick . . . Is `event_date` stored as a date?

Answer (score 0):

AHA! i figured it out! i added an event for every day of the month and i realized it just wasnt showing events that were on days 1-9. all i had to do was change DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') to DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%Y-%m-%e')